# Function identifiers not found

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run a 1D battle program I've written while using functions to declare the number of humans and skeletons. Although, it keeps giving me build errors saying that the identifiers for the functions getHumans and getSkeletons are missing.

Here are the lines which Visual Studio pointed as missing identifiers inside the int Main():

```
numHumans = getHumans();
startHumans = numHumans;
cout << "\n Rolling for attack chance... \n" << "Each human has " << (humanAttack * 100) << "% chance to hit an opponent!\n";


numSkeletons = getSkeletons();
startSkeletons = numSkeletons;
cout << "\n Rolling for attack chance.. \n" << "Each skeleton has " << (skeletonAttack * 100) << "% chance to hit an opponent!\n";
```

Here are the functions outside of the int Main()

```
int getHumans() {
int numHumans;
    cout << "Input the number of soldiers in the human army: ";
    cin >> numHumans;
    cout << "\nThe human army is " << numHumans << " men strong!";
    return numHumans; }


int getSkeletons() {
int numSkeletons;
    cout << "Input the number of skeletons in the skeleton army: ";
    cin >> numSkeletons;
    cout << "\nThe skeleton army is " << numSkeletons << " skeletons strong!";
    return numSkeletons; }
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, can anyone lend me a hand(I'm a baby steps beginner, if it wasn't obvious. :P ).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with the actual errors from the compiler.

Comment: Just guessing, but if you have the functions `getHumans()` and `getSkeletons()` defined after main(), the compiler doesn't know of their existence when it reaches them in main. Hence you need to declare them before main. Just write  lines: `int getHumans();` and `int  getSkeletons();` before main. The definitions (stuff with source code) can still be after `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from what you've posted, but I would guess that you have your `getHumans` and `getSkeletons` functions declared bellow your `main` function. Your compiler reads from top to bottom, so if you haven't told it what those functions are when you call them, then it doesn't know they exist yet. To fix it either copy and paste the functions above main, or forward declare them like so

```
   int getSkeletons();
   int getHumans();

   int main(){
       ... 
  }
```